# How to compute percentage in each group?

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, aggregate-functions, percentage

I have a table called `events`, with 5000 entries.

Each event has a `recorded_on` field that might be null or might not be.

Each event also has an `artist` field, which is one of 10 distinct values.

Is it within the abilities of SQL (SQLite specifically) to issue a single query that will return the names of artists and what percentage of their events have null as the value for `recorded_on`? As in

```
ARTIST | PERCENTAGE RECORDED
------------------------------
Joe    | 49.2
Sarah  | 17.8
Mike   | 83.0
```

Answer (score 1):

To get one output row for each group, use GROUP BY.
`recorded_on IS NULL` is a [boolean](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#boolean_datatype) expression whose result is either `1` or `0`:

```
SELECT artist,
       100.0 * sum(recorded_on IS NULL) / count(*) AS "percentage recorded"
FROM events
GROUP BY artist;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    artist,
    ( COUNT(
        CASE recorded_on
          WHEN NULL THEN 1
          ELSE NULL 
        END
    ) / COUNT(*) ) * 100 as percentage
 from event group by artist
```

Comment: Is this surely right? I always get 0 as the figure, no matter what, though that might be my mistake in running it.

Comment: is recorded_on field Null able?

Comment: It is. And I can `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM events WHERE recorded_on IS NULL` and get back a number.